# iOS 12 support for Chrome V80 for samesite

Tags: google-chrome, ios12, samesite

iOS 12 has a known bug when setting `samesite=none`; the browser acts as if `samesite=strict` ([Reference](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients)).

Chrome V80 is changing the default behavior of cookies to be set to Lax if the value is unset ([Reference](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html)). Is it possible to support Chrome V80 on iOS 12 when I need the `samesite` value to be `none`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set both the old and new style of cookie. It isn't an ideal solution as it requires some effort on your part and involves extra cookies being stored but it should work.

To save me from repeating what is already out there, this summarises it far better than I can:
https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/#handling-incompatible-clients

Comment: Thanks for the link, that makes things more clear.

The one part I still don't understand is how either of those cookies will make it through. I would expect the new cookie to get dropped on iOS 12 since setting samesite=none is treated as strict due to the bug. Then I would expect the old cookie to get dropped by chrome V80. Since samesite is not explicitly set chrome will default the value to Lax - resulting in my cookie getting dropped. 

I'm definitely misunderstanding something here. I'm just not sure what.

Comment: All browsers on iOS 12 are affected by the SameSite=Strict bug (even Chrome). That's because, under the hood, they all use the iOS network stack. Chrome 80 on iOS is not going to get the new SameSite behavior, for the same reason -- the iOS network stack doesn't use the new SameSite rules yet.